# Django question: Want to display only one number

Tags: python, html, django, view

Hello I have a set of numbers in Django Defined as:

```
def order_list_service(request, type_id = 1):
   orders = models.Order.objects.filter(is_hot = False, is_storage = False, orderservicelist__service__type = type_id).order_by('pk').distinct()
   request.session['orders']= orders

def service_order(request, client_id = 0, request_type = 1):
   orders = request.session['orders']
   return render_to_response('service_step1.html', {'orders':orders }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

In my service order view I have a template. In this template It display the list of order numbers.

```
{%for order in orders%}
        {{order.pk}}
{%endfor%}
```

This is good However I just want to display just one order number. It could be any number from that list.

Comment: `The order number I want to display is the number` <- this is pretty confusing. Do you know which one you want to get from the list? The first one? Second? Last?

Comment: What drugs was I on last evening ..., Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either limit the order to one object in the view, or in the template.

In the view:

```
   order = orders[0], orders.get(id=3), etc.
   return render_to_response('service_step1.html', {'orders':order }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

In the template:

```
   {{ orders.0.id }}
   {{ orders.5.id }}
```

But yeah shezzy, your question is confusing :)